# How can you concat columns from different tables and store it into a third Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

To summarize my question I have three tables

```
create table a 
(
     id int not null identity,
     aname varchar(16)
)

create table b 
(
     id int not null identity,
     bname varchar(16)
)

create table c 
(
     id int not null identity,
     abname varchar(16) not null,
     random varchar(16) not null
)
```

I want to concat `aname` and `bname` and store the result into `abname`.

Comment: which database ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan sql server

Comment: So what are your join rules for `a` and `b`? What's point of having unique random varchar column if  you have identity column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert all possible combinations of names from **a** and **b** you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO c (abname, random)
SELECT CONCAT(a.aname,a.bname), 999
FROM a 
CROSS JOIN b
```

If you want them joined by ID then you'd do this:

```
INSERT INTO c (abname, random)
SELECT CONCAT(a.aname,b.bname), 999
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

**P.D.:** I inserted 999 into `random` because the column is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add distinct here to avoid dupes.  Also you can use '+' instead of concat if youd like:

```
INSERT INTO c (abname, random)
SELECT Distinct  a.aname+' '+a.bname , 0
FROM a 
CROSS JOIN b
```